# unity vr building errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm working on a vr game on unity but i dont have a vr currently so i'm using Mock HMD Loader so i can simulate vr controllers in editor. After building the game, i used driver4vr and joycons instead of vr controllers and they works perfectly in other vr games but not in my game. Now i made a new project and export and the game is not even opening and shows this error:

[image]

**thank you so much for your help!**